# Can't get module to show in static block

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block, modal

Using Magento 2
I created a cms static block that points to

{{block class="Inchoo\ModalOverlay\Block\etc" template="modal_overlay.phtml"}}

I followed this guide on how to create the modal

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-how-to-display-static-block-content-in-modal-overlay/

but once its saved I get a error msg "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content."

turned on developer mode and I dont get any other details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, Flush cache and refresh page again.

```
{{block class="Inchoo\ModalOverlay\Block\ModalOverlay" name="overlay" template="Inchoo_ModalOverlay::modal_overlay.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks but yea still does not display but this time no error message.

Comment: Please check my edited answer and try again.

Comment: Still not sure why but it still is not loading it.. Im a beginner with magento 2 but have followed the instructions 100% and nothing.